# Identify this map projection.

Tags: reference-request

A loxodrome on the surface of the earth is a curve of constant bearing: it meets every parallel of latitude at the same angle.  Suppose its bearing is $\theta$ north of east, i.e. due east is $\theta=0$; due north is $\theta=\text{a right angle}$; due west is $\theta=\text{a half circle}$.  Its whole length as it goes from the south pole to the north pole is fairly routinely seen to be $\pi R\csc\theta$ where $R$ is the radius of the earth (in particular if it goes straight east, it circles the earth infinitely many times without getting closer to either pole, so its length is $\infty$).  Let this loxodrome pass through the point whose longitude and latitude are both $0$.  That is a point in the Atlantic Ocean off the coast of Africa.  I had a ninth-grade teacher who told the class that that is **"nowhere"**.  So suppose one starts at "nowhere" and travels a certain distance in a certain direction along this loxodrome and arrives at geographic location $p$.  Let $f(p)$ be the point in the $(x,y)$-plane reached by going that same distance in that same direction from $(0,0)$.  So $f(p)\in\mathbb{R}\times[-\pi R/2,\pi R/2]$.  More than one loxodrome can take you from "nowhere" to $p$, but there is a unique shortest one: the one that doesn't cross the $180^\circ$ meridian on its way from "nowhere" to $p$.  If we keep all of them, making $f$ "multiple-valued", then infinitely many copies of the earth get mapped into that strip; if we keep only the shortest one, we map the earth into a sort of oval centered at $(0,0)$ and mapping the poles to $(0,\pm \pi R/2)$.

This map projection is readily seen to be far from conformal.  It preserves distances along the shortest loxodrome from "nowhere" to $p$, but I doubt it preserves lengths of other loxodromes or great-circle distances.

What is this map projection called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, this projection is known as a
loximuthal projection with central latitude 0. It is hard to find good
references for this. The best mathematical description I have been able
to locate is in [this PDF](http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj.4.3.I2.pdf).

Comment: Thank you.  I find that Wikipedia has no article titled "loximuthal projection", but it has more than 50 articles that link to that title.

Comment: I've now created a rather stubby new article with that title.

Comment: Maybe you can add the description you gave in the question to the Wikipedia article? It's the clearest one I have seen so far.

Comment: There seems to be an image [with the desired centre](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/map/loximuthalprojection.html)